# A differential equation 

Tags: differential-equations, fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes

let $g(s)$ be real-valued function defined on $[0,T]$ such that $g(T)=0$  and suppose that $g$ is a  "nice function" 
Assume that  $0<\gamma<1$, $v$ is a positive number, and 
$$\frac{dg}{ds}+(v\gamma) g +(1-\gamma)(e^{\rho s}g)^{\frac{1}{\gamma-1}}g=0$$

Find a closed form for $g$?

Comment: Up to an implicit algebraic equation, yes.  Ask Maple.  The answer is large enough that I won't paste it here.  But it's not so hard to do even by hand!

Comment: Please provide some context: why are you interested in this equation?  Why do you particularly want a closed form (given that so many ODEs don't have closed forms)?  What have you done already to try to find one?

Comment: If possible, please give more information in the title of your question.  Titles on MO can be up to 240 characters --- almost two tweets.

Comment: This reads like homework.  I'm voting to close. I echo Theo's plea for a more descriptive title.


Comment: Hey guys, thanks for your comments, by letting $h=(e^{\rho s}g)^{\frac{1}{1-\gamma}}$ I got the solution for this ! 



Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a Bernoulli differential equation. Please cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_differential_equation for the solution (in your case $n= \frac{\gamma}{\gamma-1}$).